# JQuery put rectangle on map on page load

Tags: jquery

I currently have a map that allows it to place a rectangle on it when the image is clicked, it looks like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(document).on('click', 'img', function (ev) {
      $(".marker").remove();
      $("form#pointform").append(            
        $('<div class="marker"></div>').css({
          position: 'absolute',
          top: ev.pageY - 4 + 'px',
          left: ev.pageX - 4 + 'px',
          width: '5px',
          height: '5px',
          background: '#fff'
        })              
      );
    }); 
});
</script>
```

I also have a different function that determines the coordinates on the map for that and returns a percentage of that (so the image is 0.0 top left, to 1 on right bottom).
Now I would like to display the rectangle on the map on page load, to see the current position (for example 0.6 X-coordinate and 0.84 Y-coordinate, these values are already stored, i just need a dot on that position)

The image is here in the html:

```
<form name="pointform" method="post" id="pointform">
    <div id="pointer_div">
        <img src="url/to/my/map.png" width="500" height="300" id="cross" style="position:relative;">
    </div>
</form>
```

I don't really know JQuery so I was wondering how can I accomplish to put a rectangle on a specific place on that image? All help is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make a setMarker function that accepts an x and y position, then you can call it both on click and at page load.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(document).on('click', 'img', function (ev) {
      $(".marker").remove();
      setMarker(ev.pageX,ev.pageY);
    });

    setMarker($('#cross').width()*.6,$('#cross').height()*.84);
});

function setMarker(xPos,yPos){
    $("form#pointform").append(            
        $('<div class="marker"></div>').css({
          position: 'absolute',
          top: yPos - 4 + 'px',
          left: xPos - 4 + 'px',
          width: '5px',
          height: '5px',
          background: '#fff'
        })              
    );
}
```